# Use shell variable inside a pattern in awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file with tab-separated columns which I'd like to process using awk.

Here's an example of such a file:

```
size=1\tname=foo\tweight=1.2
weight=2.5\tname=bar\tsize=2
```

What I want to achieve is to normalize the numeric value in columns whose content is like `$field_name=<number>` to four decimal places and keep the rest as is. Here, `$field_name` is a shell variable that is passed to awk and I'd like to use its value inside a regex.

Here's a snippet (which is not working of course). I'm particularly interested in fixing line #5 in the following awk script and not solutions using other tools, such as sed, perl, python, etc.

```
$ cat "${file}" \                                       # 1
    | awk -F "\t" -v field_name="${external_var}" '     # 2
      {                                                 # 3
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {                     # 4
          if ($i ~ /$field_name=[0-9]*.?[0-9]+/) {      # 5
            split($i, kv, "=")                          # 6
            $i = sprintf("%s=%.4f", kv[1], kv[2])       # 7
          }                                             # 8
        }                                               # 9
        print $0                                        # 10
      }'
```

Comment: In your sample `$external_var` is a *shell variable*, but `field_name` is a **`awk`** variable (and `$field_name`, same as `$ fieldname` or `$ (fieldname)` would be the awk `$` operator applied to the contents of the `field_name` variable to retrieve the corresponding field of the input record), so the title and description of your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: See [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be:

```
if ($i ~ field_name "=[0-9]*.?[0-9]+") ...
```

Or:

```
 regexp = field_name "=[0-9]*.?[0-9]+"
 if ($i ~ regexp) ...
```

Note that `.` matches any single character. If you want to match a literal `.`, you'd need `regexp` to contain `\.` (which inside double quotes would have to be written `\\.`) or `[.]`.

```
 regexp = field_name "=[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+"
```

I'd also expect you'd want to anchor the regexp:

```
 regexp = "^" field_name "=[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$"
```

Other notes:

- `cat "${file}"` is a UUOC which also has the drawback (over a redirection) that it doesn't work when `$file` starts with `-` and still runs `awk` if the file can't be opened.
- `-v field_name="$external_data"` mangles backslashes. Another approach that doesn't have the problem is to use an environment variable: `FIELD="$external_data" awk ...` and refer to it within `awk` as `ENVIRON["FIELD"]`.
- as the contents of `field_name` is copied verbatim into `regexp`, it is treated as a regexp, so if `$external_data` contains regexp operators (`.+*?{}()[]\^%`...), it may not work properly.
- in some locales and `awk` implementations, `[0-9]` matches a lot more characters than just `0123456789` (though I suspect it would be (non-ASCII) characters unlikely to occur in your input).

With `perl`:

```
FIELD=size <"$file" perl -lpe '
  s{
    (?<![^\t])       # not-preceded by a non-TAB
    \Q$ENV{FIELD}=\E # contents of $FIELD taken literally
    \K               # matched portion starts here
    \d*\.?\d+
    (?![^\t])        # not followed by a non-TAB
  }{
    sprintf "%.4f", $&
  }gxe'
```

Which would not have any of the issues discussed above (it would also work better than `awk` with input that contains invalid text, like a mix of text and binary data, or text encoded in a charset different from that of the user's locale).

Comment: Thanks, Stéphane! This nicely solved my problem.