# passing shell variable to awk and get awk output in shell variable

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk

I have passed argument to `myscript.sh` that returns a value in variable `m`. Problem is that I am  not able to pass shell variable (`runvalues`) to awk script that search for a pattern. Therefore value of m is NULL always

```
runvalues=2;
m=$( awk -v d="$runvalues" '/internal=d/{p=NR} p && /Cp=/{print FILENAME; exit}' $1) ;
```

I run script as `myscript.sh file1.txt`, where file1.txt contains

```
runvalue internal=1 
runvalue internal=2
runvalue internal=3
```

Comment: You can't use variables in regular expressions. Try `m=$( awk "/internal=$runvalues/"'{p=NR} p && /Cp=/{print FILENAME; exit}' $1)`

Comment: `/internal=d/` is a regex constant - `d` will be interpreted literally. You could use a dynamic regex by concatenating the string `"internal="` with the *value of* `d` using `$0 ~ "internal="d`. See for example [Use shell variable inside a pattern in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/592669/use-shell-variable-inside-a-pattern-in-awk)

Comment: Do not do `"/internal=$runvalues/"` as suggested in a comment as it leads to cryptic errors, see [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script). @steeldriver's approach is correct though I'm never sure if `$0 ~ "internal="d` means `$0 ~ ("internal="d)` or `($0 ~ "internal=")d` so I personally would always parenthesise that as the former for clarity if nothing else.

Comment: @berndbausch Nice code injection vulnerability you've got there ;-)

Comment: Removing Bobby Tables via awk. I hope they control `runvalues` - but I agree it's ugly and steeldriver's is much superior.